# Integration of $\sqrt { x^2 + a^2 } $ by substitution.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution

When we take $x=a\tan \theta$, then $\sqrt { x^2 + a^2 } =a\mid\sec\theta\mid$. Why do we not use the modulus, why do we simply write $\sec\theta$?

Answer (score 6):

Here $\theta$ is (implicitly) between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$. We really are making the ordinary substitution $\theta=\arctan(x/a)$.  On the interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ the secant is positive.

Comment: what about (x^2-a^2)^(1/2)... where we take x to be asec(theta)... there what is the interval in which theta lies... it will be zero to pie... so what about tan(theta)

Comment: In that case we really do have to take absolute value.  Your question was a very valid one, it is just that in the particular example you chose we can leave the absolute value out.